# В чем ошибка? файл .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redbeanphp

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ api.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

API

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require 'db.php';
echo json_encode(array("status" => "321321"));

$type = $_GET['q'];
$key = R::findOne('users', 'vk_id = ?', array($type));
if ($key) {
  if ($key->balance > 5) {
    echo json_encode(array("status" => True));
  }else {
    echo json_encode(array("status" => False));
  }
}else {
  http_response_code(404);
 }



?>
```

Есть сайт, я сделал простой апи
Тестил на openserver все работает
Залил на хостинг не работает(

Comment: и в чем это выражается? что в логе?

Comment: Я пишу в site.ru/api/3241223
Он ничего не выводит

Comment: Скорее всего почему-то переменная q не работает

Comment: ДА я проверил
переменная q не работает
Почему? я не знаю 
Вы умнее помогите!!)

Comment: дак вы для начала сделайте `print_r($_GET)` и посмотрите, что там есть ваши `api/3241223`. еще вероятно и статус 404 возвращается.

Comment: Выводится все правильно
Я сделал но только когда поменял 

$key = R::findOne('users', 'vk_id = ?', array($type));
на
$key = R::findOne('users', 'id = ?', array($type));
и ввел 1 в url
Почему столбец vk_id он не принимает?